# When is it appropriate to use "SELECT *" in a Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, triggers

When is it appropriate to use `SELECT *`  in a stored procedure?

Comment: In my opinion, never! [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

Comment: Why do you think it is ever appropriate to use `SELECT *`?

Comment: I agree it's a bad practice, but there are some cases in where you **need** that the result of an SP changes as the table changes. Thinking in Data Dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Use of `SELECT *` for a stored procedure's output is bad practice. When the underlying tables change, the output of a `SELECT *` query will change leading to potential issues. If the SP provides data for a web application, part of that webapp may break. If the SP is executed by a batch process, the process may fail leading to other issues including angry DBAs.

One situation where `SELECT *` is OK is in the context of an `IF EXISTS` check:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.myTable)
BEGIN
  -- do something
END
```

Edit: However, you can just as easily use `SELECT 1` to satisfy an `IF EXISTS` check.

Comment: select null does the same

Comment: yes, it doesn't matters what you put in the Select. `If Exists (Select 1/0 From Table) ...` compiles and works.